# Syntax error due to a default alias (_c3)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I used a query to create a table, which has a SET in one of its columns.

T1:

```
    serial   _c3
1   193748   ["special","normal","normal"]
2   263565   ["normal","normal"]
```

Then I have another Table with serials only.

T2:

```
    serial   
1   193748  
2   263565
3   636474
4   928396
```

I want a query that produces serials from T2 IF they are NOT in T1 or if T1's _c3 data has the word "special" in it. I also want a boolean value that indicates if T1 is in T2.

So using above example, I want:

T3:

```
    serial   in_t1 
1   193748   1
3   636474   0
4   928396   0
```

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT 
    T2.serial,
    array_contains(T1._c3, 'special') as in_t1
FROM T2 LEFT OUTER JOIN T1 ON T1.serial = T2.serial
WHERE T1.serial is NULL OR array_contains(T1._c3, 'special')
LIMIT 50;
```

So for array_contains in select line I get this error message:

Error while compiling statement: FAILED:  cannot recognize input near 'T1' '.' '_c3' in select expression.

When I remove that line from select and just run:

```
SELECT 
    T2.serial
FROM T2 LEFT OUTER JOIN T1 ON T1.serial = T2.serial
WHERE T1.serial is NULL OR array_contains(T1._c3, 'special')
LIMIT 50;
```

I get the same error but in the WHERE clause line now: cannot recognize input near 'T1' '.' '_c3' in select expression

Could you point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: `_c3` is illegal alias/column name, due to the underscore as its first character. Use `\`_c3\`` instead (or rename the column or even better, alias your expressions in the first place)

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much. If you write it as an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_c3` is illegal alias/column name, due to the underscore as its first character.
If you want to use it, wrap it with ticks signs (`).
Anther option would be to rename to column.
The cleanest solution would have been to alias the expression in the first place.